# Vue stating that a property is undefined, when I clearly defined it

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-property-decorator

For a project I am trying to create a page where the user can edit a post. A post has it's content and 0 or more images. As it is saved on the database in different tables, I have created two endpoints on the Backend (/posts, /images).

## The problem

On the edit component I am trying to use a Set datatype to keep track of which part of the post has been edited (post content or post images). The relevant parts of the component code for that is below.

```js
...
@Component({
  components: { ckeditor: CKEditor.component, ImageListCard },
})
export default class ObjectEditView extends MainShell {
  private _changes = new Set<EditedAttributes>();
  ...
```

EditedAttributes is an enum containing the different Attributes of the post that can be edited. Upon submitting there is code to check which endpoint(s) should be submitted to.

Whenever I load the page in my browser, I get the following error upon loading.

`TypeError: this._changes is undefined`

What I find really weird is that it says `_changes` is undefined when I clearly defined `_changes` as a new Set.

## What I've tried

I've tried the following things, to no avail.

- declaring `_changes` on the class and then defining it in a constructor.
- Setting `_changes` to a new Set in the browser console, which worked but obviously isn't a solution.
- setting `_changes` to a new instance of a Set again in the created hook.
- setting `_changes` to a new instance of a Set again in the mounted hook.

I can of course just make a boolean out of _changes and make requests to all the endpoints on every submit action. This however will put unnecessary load on the API. I can also change the Set into an array, but I've chosen for a Set since an item can only be applied once to it.

If someone could explain to me why it says it is undefined when I clearly defined it, or provide a solution for this that'd be really awesome :D.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution myself already. I set _changes in the mounted hook and added a component state which on the "ready" state would load the component. Therefore _changes won't be attempted to read when it is still in its undefined state.